# IdentityServer4 refresh_token revocation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have SPA app that uses IdentityServer4 ROPC flow for auth with access and refresh tokens from this example https://github.com/robisim74/AngularSPAWebAPI. Every 15 minutes I update refresh_token for a new pair of refresh and access tokens.

However If I restart IdentityServer4 app old refresh_tokens issued before restart no longer valid. How to fix it? I suspect I should implement some interface to store issued refresh tokens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement persisted grants by using the `IPersistedGrantStore` contract. This stores things like refresh_tokens into a defined persistence. By default IdentityServer 4 will use an InMemory persistence store, which is why you keep on losing your refresh_token references when you restart the application.

It is pretty much mandatory to have a persistence layer for this in production if you are going to be using refresh_tokens.